# How to extract specific response into csv file in JMeter?

Tags: regex, jmeter, beanshell

In my webservices test plan, I am sending SOAP request for login with *username* and in the response data it sends back:

> - username
> - session id (unique value example:12234546)

I want to save that username and session id into a CSV file.

Comment: provide some details....

Comment: Can you paste your response data or show us how are you fetching username and sessionId?

Answer (score 1):

You should use [XPath Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Extractor) to extract each one in a variable.

You can use XPathTest in [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) to test the XPath expression on the response.

And you can then serialize variables in CSV by setting in user.properties files:

> sample_variables=username,sessionid

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with Beanshell. Something like:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

Sting username = vars.get("username");

String RegexMethod(String user) {
    String regResult = null;
    StringBuilder regex = new StringBuilder(",username:\");
    regex.append(user).append(",password:\"(.+?)\".");

    try {
        Pattern pat = Pattern.compile(regex);
        Matcher mac = pat.matcher(text);
        mac.find();
        regResult = mac.group(1);
    }  catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return regResult;
}

String PATH = "/home/username/jmeterFiles/userData.csv";

try {               
    FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(PATH, true);
    fileWriter.append(username);
    fileWriter.append(",");
    fileWriter.append(RegexMethod(username));
    fileWriter.append("\n");

    fileWriter.flush();
    fileWriter.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

You can put this in the [Beanshell Post-processor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PostProcessor) and it will write data you want into the file. It maybe needs little tweaking, but you should get point. You will just need to get your regex...